# ngrx entity adapter is not updating a sub property of a required property

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0, ngrx-entity

I have an object maintained in ngrx store like shown below -

```
{
 .
 .
 callStatus: ClientStatus;
 .
 .
}
```

and ClientStatus is a further nested interface like -

```
interface ClientStatus {
 status: boolean;
 csrObject: csrStatus;
}
```

now in an API response I am getting updated values of csrStatus for a single user type which I need to update.
but when I try to -

```
adapter.updateOne(
{
  id: client.id,
  changes: { callStatus.csrObject: action.response }
})
```

I am getting error as I am not allowed to access a sub-property of a given key while updating.

Does anybody know how can I approach this problem?

Comment: in a way, i want to update a nested property in store through adapter.updateOne()

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct your code a bit:

```js
adapter.updateOne({
    id: client.id,
    csrObject: action.response
  },
  state,
})
```

ngrx doc says the first argument is a Partial entity object the second argument is the state of the entity:

```js
  on(UserActions.updateUser, (state, { update }) => {
    return adapter.updateOne(update, state);
  }),
```